# is it possible to import an inferred type of an object in Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I can have the following object in one file

```
type MyType = { createdDate: Date }
export const myObject: MyType = { createdDate: new Date() }
```

And I am interested in importing `MyType` as I import `myObject`.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be necessary to export the type.

You can infer the type by doing:

`import typeof { MyType } from 'file';`

Answer (score 0):

Change your `type` declaration to the following:

```
export type MyType = { createdDate: Date }
```

Then, in any other file, you can do:

```
import type MyType from 'file'
```

Replacing `'file'` by the actual location of your file.

[Reference.](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/modules/)